# Issue with importing org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am following a book "Hands-On Microservices with Spring Boot and Spring Cloud" by Magnus Larsson. I am using vsCode IDE for coding. With hurdles, I was able to get to 40% of the book.
I am stuck at a point where the vsCode is not able to import the following two classes

1. org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output
2. org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel

The Build tool used through out the book is Gradle. As directed, I have added the following in the dependencies in the corresponding project's build.gradle

```
    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit')
    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka')
```

I also tried adding the following in the cradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release.wiki.git
however, it did not help

Here is a portion of my build.gradle which describes the boot version, java version

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'product-composite-service'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11.0.16.1'
```

```
ext {
    springCloudVersion = "2021.0.5.RELEASE"
}
```

Also based on

This is the first time I am building a java project with Gradle & vsCode, so, please excuse my ignorance.

Regards,
Prakash

Mentioned in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer.
I switched my IDE. Using Intellij now. Everything seemed to resolve by itself.
Visual Studio Code is a great IDE. However, I now believe that we need some extra support when building spring-cloud applications. Especially when it comes to new learning.